# Adding a missing reference to Travis-CI build

Tags: c#, travis-ci

I'm working on a program that uses a Dymo labelwriter 450, using a custom reference to interact with it from my c# program. I'm using `DYMO.Label.Framework`

When I sync with GitHub and Travis tries to test the software, it can't compile because it's missing a reference. `error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DYMO' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?`

I made sure to add the DLL to the project directory and reference it from the project using a relative path.

Is there something I need to add to the travis config? I can't find the package on NuGet.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the DLL is being copied to the output directory?

Comment: @miparnisari I just checked, it's in the output directory on GitHub and also on my local system. So yes, I am very sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Travis works fine with references, even nuget packages are actually referenced by relative path. Make sure your dll is pushed to github and saved to the right place. Project directory (not bin or something) should be the basis of relative path. One more thing to note -- path strings are case-sensitive as travis works on mono.

References like this worked for me:

```
<Reference Include="Nustache.Core">
  <HintPath>..\..\Tools\Rosalia\Nustache.Core.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```